# Image loaded from black and white .mat file using PIL is not as expected

Tags: python, image, matlab

I'm trying to load a set of images from a .mat file that contains 100 images. As visible in the screenshots below, when I load the image array I expect some sort of 'O'-like shape to form due to the positions of the 1's but instead get a seemingly nonsensical image formed below. Using the 'L' option to create the image via PIL leads to a completely black image.

I am using scipyio loadmat() to open the .mat file and am using the PIL Image object to create the image. Any help is appreciated!

[Problem code and resulting array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFgWh.png)

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused as a result of each value in the array being a 1 or 0, multiplying the array by 255 causes the actual image to be realized.